# Find exact string in file works weird

Tags: python, string, file, compare

I need to find a string in a text file (here a dictionary).

The string found in the file must be exactly the same as the one I am comparing.

Here is my code and the dictionary:

*the code*

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os # pour ouvrir le dictionnaire

def check_if_exist(word,dico):
    """retourne vrai si le mot exsite dans le dictionnaire"""
    for line in dico:
        #line = line.rstrip('\n')
        # on ne peut pas utiliser in pour la condition
        # car in fait une comparaison partielle, exemple : 
        # "pal" in "empaler" ; return True
        if word.rstrip('\n') == line.rstrip('\n'):
            return True
    return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #file_path = "./dico-french.txt"
    file_path = "./dico.txt"
    # teste si le fichier existe
    if(not os.path.isfile(file_path)):
        print("le dictionnaire n'existe pas")
        exit(1)
    #ouvre le dictionnaire
    dico = open(file_path,'r')
        
    print("q pour quitter le jeu.")
    mot = input("Premier joueur, quel est votre mot ? ")
    # tant que le mot n'existe pas
    while(not check_if_exist(mot,dico)):
        mot = input("Un autre ? ")
    # le mot existe, on passe au joueur suivant
    tab = []
    tab.append(mot)
    mot_old = mot
    while mot!='q':
        print("\nles mots sont ",tab)
        mot = input("Joueur suivant, quel est votre mot ? ")
        while(not check_if_exist(mot,dico)):
            mot = input("Un autre bis ? ")
        tab.append(mot)
        mot_old = mot
    print("Bye.")
```

*the dict*

```
pal
lape
pale
palie
pallier
pallies
```

Let me explain you the problem with these examples :
for the fig n°1, the conditions seems to be met, all the words are in the dictionary.

fig n°1:

```
q pour quitter le jeu.
Premier joueur, quel est votre mot ? pal 

les mots sont  ['pal']
Joueur suivant, quel est votre mot ? pale

les mots sont  ['pal', 'pale']
Joueur suivant, quel est votre mot ? palie

les mots sont  ['pal', 'pale', 'palie']
Joueur suivant, quel est votre mot ? ^C
```

for the fig n°2, all the word are in the dictionary, but when I enter a word positioned after the one I am comparing in the dictionary, it does not find it

fig n°2:

```
q pour quitter le jeu.
Premier joueur, quel est votre mot ? palie

les mots sont  ['palie']
Joueur suivant, quel est votre mot ? pal
Un autre bis ? ^C
```

There is some kind of index that doesn't reset while I leave the function.

On the fig n°3 I try with a word not in the dictionary, this unknown word is not found, so it ask me for another word, and when I enter a known-word it doesn't work.

fig n°3:

```
q pour quitter le jeu.
Premier joueur, quel est votre mot ? pal

les mots sont  ['pal']
Joueur suivant, quel est votre mot ? hgjfdkjhgfj
Un autre bis ? pale
Un autre bis ? ^C
```

Can someone explain this to me?

EDIT:
Thanks to 'Nir H.', just have to add `dico.seek(0)` at the beginning of my function

Comment: Consider replacing the linked images with the actual text output. There are lots of reasons to do this, which are explained very well here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5906389

Comment: Try adding `dico.seek(0)` at the beginning of the `check_if_exist` function. That will make the function start at the beginning of the file at each invocation.

Comment: @NirH. thanks a lot, that's what I was looking for hours!